# Material 2 - Unexpected Token

Tags: angular, angular-material2

So I'm using a .NET WebAPI solution to use Angular 4 and Material 2. Since importing animations - `BrowserAnrimationsModule` and `NoopAnimationsModule`

I receive this error -

```
Error: Unexpected token <
  Evaluating http://localhost:9000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js/animations
```

My `app.module.ts` looks like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialComponentsModule } from './core/material-components.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing,
        MaterialComponentsModule        
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I've had this error before when I had not imported all the correct dependencies. However I now believe I have. So I'm at a lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not supposed to import both BrowserAnimationsModule & NoopAnimationsModule. The NoopAnimationsModule is a version that produces no animations at all ("noop" == "no operation"). See it as a way to disable animations (for performance reasons) without the need to remove every single animation from your app.

Comment: Hi Ploppy, I've removed the BrowserAnimationsModule and left in the Noop module. However I still receive the same error.

Comment: You should make sure angular is at least at version 4.4.3. Assuming your are using the latest @angular/material version.